# Heat map with possibility of shading any country or province in the world?

Tags: heat-map

My boss is collecting data which measures where visitors to our website are located. He wants me to make a choropleth map (I believe that's what it's called) in which countries and provinces are shaded according to how many hits they got.

For example, if we got a hit from Hungary, then Hungary will be shaded in the map, but the user can also scroll over to Hungary and zoom in and see there was actually a hit from Észak-Alföld province, and so on for every other country and sub-division.

I have done a lot of research and the only way I can see of doing this is to get a GeoJSON file for Hungary, along with every other country, and put them all on our server so we can make the maps using d3.

However, my boss refuses to believe that it can be this difficult, because there are maps all over the web made with Google Maps or OpenStreetMap, and they all have country and province boundaries, so it should be possible to shade those countries and provinces using an API.

We can certainly make a map in which the latitude and longitude of each hit is shown using a marker, but is it really not possible to make a choropleth map like this? If so, why?

Comment: Viktor Urban wants to know your location! - What research considering heat-maps and D3 have you done so far?

Comment: @Erik just naively Googling it and trying to find out whether there are any Javascript libraries which can do this. I also made a couple of maps successfully for the world and China, but my boss also wants literally everywhere else.

Comment: I also tried to do it with amCharts4, but it seemed to be causing a memory leak as the maps would disappear after updating them a few times.

Comment: You made a map of the world, but it doesn't show the area you boss wants? Sorry, I am confused.

Comment: It's actually [Choropleth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map) (no 'l', though many pronounce it that way).  Note that proxies and VPN will cause the IP_address-Location lookups to be unreliable; the more detail you provide, the more likely the map is wrong.

Comment: @Vince thank you for explaining that. Yes, I have the data and I want to display it. I am trying to find out whether that is possible.

Comment: @Erik I made a map of the world in which the countries are shaded and a map of China in which the provinces are shaded. I want to make a map of the world in which I can shade any province in any country.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the answer after talking to some people who are knowledgeable about GIS.

Basically, it is possible to make a map like this. Natural Earth has province-level data for the whole world, which can be used to make a map, although the detail level of the data varies by country (for example, Latvia is covered in extreme detail). The data also comes with a warning that it is likely to be inaccurate for many countries because it is hard to keep up to date.

The main drawback to doing this is that it makes the map extremely slow, because there are thousands of polygons.

The reason why it can't be done using the Openstreetmap API, for example, is because maps like this are actually made up of images, called [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles), which, being images, do not contain the boundary polygon data, and therefore the boundaries cannot be shaded.

I am posting this answer, not because I am in any way interested in contributing to your site, but in the hope that it might be useful for people who have a similar question in the future.